# Checkout conditional fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a WooCommerce running for selling travel tours. The problem is that one visitor can buy a tour for four people and or every person on the trip we need get their full_name , number_rg and cellphone_

Now we can easily get the needed fields to be displayed in checkout page, however there has to be a condition on a quantity of product (travel tour) bought.

I did a lot of research and I could only find conditional fields based on product_id, but nothing based on the quantity of a product, so I hope this question will be helpful for others.

Any help or guindace is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the items in the cart via `WC()->cart->get_cart()`. You will then have access to things like the product id, variation id and category id(s) of all items in your cart.

So for instance you can check if your tour product is in the cart by checking for a certain product id. Then add a number of custom checkout fields equal to the quantity of that specific product in the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_fields_based_on_quantity' ); 
function custom_checkout_fields_based_on_quantity( $checkout ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == '123' ) {

            echo '<div id="fellow_travellers"><h4>Group information</h4>';

            for ( $x = 1; $x <= $cart_item['quantity']; $x++ ) {

                woocommerce_form_field( 'fellow_traveller_full_name_' . $x, array(
                        'type'          => 'text',
                        'required'      => true,
                        'class'         => array( 'my-class form-row-wide' ),
                        'label'         => sprintf( '%s %s', __( 'Full name fellow traveller' ), $x ),
                        'placeholder'   => __( 'John Doe' ),
                    )
                );

            }

            echo '</div>';
        } 
    }
}
```

By that same logic you can process the checkout and save your custom checkout fields as described here: [WooCommerce checkout - Adding a custom special field](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.